# ARKit Barcode tracking and Vision framework

Tags: swift, barcode, arkit, apple-vision

I have been trying to draw bounding box for QR code detected during ARSession. The result is:
[boundingbox 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlxdF.jpg)
[boundingbox 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5AKR.jpg)

The barcode is being tracked, but the geometry of bounding box is wrong.

How to get correct coordinates of bounding box?

The source code is:

```
 public func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

     // Only run one Vision request at a time
     if self.processing {
         return
     }

    self.processing = true

    let request = VNDetectBarcodesRequest { (request, error) in

        if let results = request.results, let result = results.first as? VNBarcodeObservation {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let path = CGMutablePath()

                for result in results {
                    guard let barcode = result as? VNBarcodeObservation else { continue }
                    let topLeft = self.convert(point: barcode.topLeft)
                    path.move(to: topLeft)
                    let topRight = self.convert(point: barcode.topRight)
                    path.addLine(to: topRight)
                    let bottomRight = self.convert(point: barcode.bottomRight)
                    path.addLine(to: bottomRight)
                    let bottomLeft = self.convert(point: barcode.bottomLeft)
                    path.addLine(to: bottomLeft)
                    path.addLine(to: topLeft)
                }                   
                self.drawLayer.path = path
                self.processing = false
            }
        } else {
            self.processing = false
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        do {
            request.symbologies = [.QR]
            let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: frame.capturedImage, orientation: .right, options: [:])                
            try imageRequestHandler.perform([request])
        } catch {               
        }
    }
}

 private func convert(point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
     return CGPoint(x: point.x * view.bounds.size.width,
                   y: (1 - point.y) * view.bounds.size.height)
 }
```

Comment: If you Command-click on VNRectangleObservation, the documentation of the class says you are supposed to use *CIPerspectiveTransform* to straighten it up. I am not sure it will resolve the issue, though. Maybe it has something to do with delay between the current frame and the frame where the code was found.

Comment: The only way working for me is to take a snapshot:
let snapshot = self.sceneView.snapshot().rotate(radians: -.pi/2)
But this way is not good because I have to take a snapshot of the frame that already taken during tracking and snapshot resolution is low. I guess normal way must exist.

Comment: Can it be related to 'orientation: .right'? Perhaps it should be '.up' then?

Comment: I tried different orientations, it's not a case of orientation. When I took image frame from ARFrame and from Snapshot, to images had different dimmensions and different content as if two images was shot at different angles of view.

Comment: I would try saving some of ARFrames to the filesystem as CGImages and running VNDetectBarcodesRequest on saved images to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I just migrated barcode recognition in my app from AVFoundation to Vision, and here's what works for me as outlining logic:

```html
extension CVPixelBuffer {
    var size: CGSize {
        get {
            let width = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(self))
            let height = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(self))
            return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        }
    }
}
extension VNRectangleObservation {    
    func outline(in cvPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, with color: UIColor) -> CALayer {
        let outline = CAShapeLayer()
        outline.path = self.path(in: cvPixelBuffer).cgPath
        outline.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        outline.strokeColor =  color.cgColor
        return outline
    }
    
    func path(in cvPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> UIBezierPath {
        let size = cvPixelBuffer.size
        let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            .scaledBy(x: 1, y: -1)
            .translatedBy(x: 0, y: -size.height)
            .scaledBy(x: size.width, y: size.height)
        
        let convertedTopLeft = self.topLeft.applying(transform)
        let convertedTopRight = self.topRight.applying(transform)
        let convertedBottomLeft = self.bottomLeft.applying(transform)
        let convertedBottomRight = self.bottomRight.applying(transform)
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: convertedTopLeft)
        path.addLine(to: convertedTopRight)
        path.addLine(to: convertedBottomRight)
        path.addLine(to: convertedBottomLeft)
        path.close()
        
        path.lineWidth = 2.0
        return path
    }
}
```

After that, I apply one more scale transform to adapt to the size of the view where the outline is shown.

I am using https://github.com/maxvol/RxVision library which makes it simple to pass the processed image (CVPixelBuffer in my case) along the line.